# How can I prove this inequality using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I am reading introduction to functional analysis with application of Kreyzig.
The question in excercise is 
"Show that Cauchy-Schwarz inequality implies that
$$(|a_{1}|+|a_{2}|+...+|a_{n}|)^2\leq n(|a_{1}|^2+|a_{2}|^2+...+|a_{n}|^2).$$"
The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is
$$\sum|\zeta_{j}\eta_{j}|\leq (\sum|\zeta_{j}|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} (\sum|\eta_{j}|^q)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$
 Thanks in advance

Comment: First, write down the Cauchy Schwarz inequality that you know. This will help those who are trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to Cauchy Schwartz,
$[\sum_{i=1}^{n} {|a_i|}^2][\sum_{i=1}^{n} {|b_i|}^2\geq \sum_{i=1}^{n} {(|a_i||b_i|)}^2$

put $b_i=1$ for all i you get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Observe we may suppose $a_i\ge 0$ for all $i=11,\dots n$. Next apply Cauchy-Schwarz to the vectors $\;(a_1,a_2, \dots, a_n)\;$  and $\;(1,1,\dots, 1)$.